# Is there a bash expression I could use to check whether current commit is tagged?

Tags: bash, git

I'm looking for a bash expression to check whether current git commit is tagged.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your Git is not too far out of date:

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

will print out the names of tags that, if checked out, result in a detached-HEAD checkout of the current commit.  If this list is empty, there are no such tags; if not, there is at least one tag.  So: count the number of tags and see if it's nonzero, or check to see if the output of the command is non-empty.  (The command's exit status is zero regardless of how many tags it produces.)

```
if [ $(git tag --points-at HEAD | wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then echo yes; fi
```

or:

```
if [ -n "$(git tag --points-at HEAD)" ]; then echo yes; fi
```

will do the trick, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have git installed on your system, you can try **git tag --points-at HEAD**. This would list the tags associated with latest commit. You cannot get git tags without having git in your system.